# Getting error while deploying keycloak docker image to Heroku

Tags: docker, keycloak

I am pretty new to Heroku.

I am trying to deploy a keycloak docker image to heroku. I am getting this error while building the keycloak docker image.

`!     No default language could be detected for this app.`
`HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.`
`See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks`
`!     Push failed`

Any idea why is this happening ?

What is the build pack i need to select ?

My docker file looks like this

````
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /opt/jboss/tools

ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/jboss/tools/docker-entrypoint.sh" ]
CMD ["-b", "0.0.0.0"]```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this: [Github keycloak-heroku](https://github.com/mieckert/keycloak-heroku).

You can deploy using the [deploy button from heroku](https://elements.heroku.com/buttons/mieckert/keycloak-heroku) or you can build and push your own image from the latest keycloak version. In my experience, you should use a dyno with at least 1 Gb ram for keycloak 11.

Comment: Try building the image locally and run it using `docker run -p 8080:8080 -e PORT=8080 your_image`. After that, push the image to heroku registry and deploy. See the guide here: [heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime)

Comment: Is 1Gb ram enough to run Keycloak with  good performance?

Comment: I don't think Heroku is adequate for running keycloak in production the infinispan cache will reset on the daily dyno restart